# Shared Preferences implementation

Tags: c++, qt

My aim was to implement a class that can be accessible from anywhere, providing key value pairs;

```
class SharedResources
{
public:
    static QMap <QString,QVariant> *preferences;
};

//initialization
SharedResources.preferences = new QMap<QString,QVariant>();

//store data
SharedResources.preferences->insert("some_data",some_data);

//access data
some_data = SharedResources.preferences->value("some_data");
```

but this code does not compile.

First error (got a similar at every usage):

```
/file:line: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
 SharedResources.preferences = new QMap<QString,QVariant>();
                ^
```

I definitely broke some c++ rules, but what those are?

Update: Using :: the error is:

```
/file:line: error: undefined reference to `SharedResources::preferences'
```

Comment: static members are access via `::` and not via `.`

Comment: True, thanks, I guess I can delete it, since it is too trivial.

Comment: Well it still does not work.

Comment: Trivial is not necessarily uninteresting for others. Maybe if you change the title (e.g. something like "problem initializing static member") the question might be fine. On the other hand, there might be duplicates already

Comment: The () in your initialization might not be doing what you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better in such a case to use statically rather than dynamically allocated memory (i.e. without `new`).

Your problem is that you have to declare and **define** your static field as well. In the header file you only declare it, it should be defined somewhere in the `cpp` file like:

```
// this defines the variable, with default ctor (w/out parameters)
QMap<QString,QVariant> SharedResources::preferences;
```

Of course you have to link the appropriate object file to your other modules (apart from using header file with the declaration).

Comment: Using static field, instead of pointer: QMap<QString,QVariant> SharedResources::preferences = QMap<QString,QVariant>();

Comment: I updated the answer according to your suggestion. (Theoretically reducing unnecessary copying, which could be optimized out by compiler.)

Answer (score 2):

As I already pointed out in the comment, static members are accessed via `::` and not via `.`

I guess the reason is that `.` is an operator that needs an object, while static members are accessed without an object.

Comment: Might make sense to show the corrected code that compiles, there might be more than just that issue

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Indeed, it would be better if the OP would post an MCVE, because I am not sure where he wants the initialization/store data/access data to take place.

Comment: Strange how in depth, difficult problems with MCVE get less attention than simple questions without one

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum \begin{offtopic} I guess it is just easier to collect rep on questions that are not really well defined by giving "handwaving" answers. I used to comment rather than give an answer when I was not really sure what is the actual problem. However, recently I changed my mind a bit and rely on downvotes / better answers that can be given by others once the question has been clarified. \end{offtopic}